# Ajax callback no response

Tags: php, jquery, callback, validation

I use below script to retrieve callback result, but nothing are return when the form is submit, what is wrong with the code below? and how to make each errors output to the div tag with `id='msg'`?

here is my full script of register form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#wait').hide();
$('#wait').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$('#btn_register').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#register_form').serialize();
    //alert(parameters);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "error"){
                alert('Error: '+ output_str);

            }else{
                alert(output_str);
                //$('#result_msg').html(output_str);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });

});

});
</script>

<div class="content">
<div>
    <div class="title-bar" align="center"><h2 class="title">Registration Form</h2></div>

    <div class="inner-wrap pad">
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <div align="center">
        <form action="" method="post" id="register_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" class="tb">
          <tr>
            <td width="30%" class="r"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
            <td width="70%"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" value="" autofocus autocomplete="off" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="rpassword">Retype Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="rpassword" name="rpassword" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['rpassword']) ? $_POST['rpassword'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="fname">Full Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="contact">Contact Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contact']) ? $_POST['contact'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="dob">Date of Birth</label></td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="dd" name="dd" style="width:24px;" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['dd']) ? $_POST['dd'] : '' ?>" placeholder="dd" />&nbsp;/
            <input type="text" id="mm" name="mm" style="width:24px;" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['mm']) ? $_POST['mm'] : '' ?>" placeholder="mm" />&nbsp;/
            <input type="text" id="yy" name="yy" style="width:40px;" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['yy']) ? $_POST['yy'] : '' ?>" placeholder="yyyy" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="capcha"></label></td>
            <td>
            <div style="padding-bottom:3px;">
            <img id="captcha" src="inc/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='inc/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false" class="capcha">Refresh</a>
            </div>
            <div><input type="text" name="ct_captcha" size="12" maxlength="8" id="capcha" style="width:100px;" /></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn" id="btn_register">Proceed</a>&nbsp;<span id="wait"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

request.php

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');
include('functions.php');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($_POST['email'])));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

$error = NULL;
if(!check_email_address($email)){
    $error .= "<li>Invalid Email Address";
}
if(empty($password) || strlen($password) < 0){
    $error .= "<li>Invalid Password";
}

// if found invalid input
if(!empty($error)){
    $output_str = "error";
}else{
    $output_str = "No Error";   
}


echo json_encode($output_str);

?>
```

Thanks.

**Update:**

console error:

```
[Object { readyState=

4

,  responseText=

"<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  ...<b>14</b><br />\n"error""

,  status=

200

,  more...}, 

"parsererror"

, 

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]   

return window.JSON.parse( data );

jquery-1.7.2.js (line 564)

]


0
Object { readyState=

4

, responseText=

"<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  ...<b>14</b><br />\n"error""

, status=

200

, more...}

1


"parsererror"


2


SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]   

return window.JSON.parse( data );

jquery-1.7.2.js (line 564)
```

Comment: Probably, it never comes to your success at all. Try adding a error block (timeouts too come here)

Comment: Can you check your browser console for any errors in the ajax call. What is the error in there ?

Comment: @Sabari, please see my error from firebug console.

Comment: @conmen where did you add the error ? I din't see it anywhere

Comment: did you write this return window.JSON.parse( data ); any where

Comment: looks like you have an error in db function.. tat is why you getting jsonparse error unexpected characters.. check yout `check_email_address` fynction

Comment: @conmen I think you have some undefined variable issue in your code. EIther in connect.php or  functions.php. Can you check the line number specified in the notice error in the console. Since PHP produces the notice the jquery decoder finds unexpected characters. Please find that and resolve. Also try setting ini_set('display_errors', 0) in your PHP file to remove errors from showing. Let me know the result then

Comment: @Sabari, the alert can be pop now, there is some $_POST values error. If you don't mind, is there able to show each invalid error message output to the `<div>` block? thank you for your clues.

Comment: @conmen Do you want to ouput each error message to its corresponding block ?? Can you show me your html

Comment: @Sabari, I re-edit my post to show full html form. Please kindly advise.

Comment: @conmen OK let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update HTML for you. Let me know if this helps you.

**Register Form HTML and Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#wait').hide();
   $('#wait').ajaxStart(function() {
      $(this).show();
   }).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $(this).hide();
   });

   $('#btn_register').click(function(){
       var parameters = $('#register_form').serialize();
      $('.error').empty();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           if (response.success == 'success') {
               //do the things you need on success
           } else {
               if (response.error.email != '') {
                   $('#email_error').html(response.error.email);
               }
               if (response.error.password != '') {
                   $('#password_error').html(response.error.password);
               }
           } 
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
     });

   });

});
</script>

<div class="content">
<div>
    <div class="title-bar" align="center"><h2 class="title">Registration Form</h2></div>

    <div class="inner-wrap pad">
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <div align="center">
        <form action="" method="post" id="register_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" class="tb">
          <tr>
            <td width="30%" class="r"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
            <td width="70%">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" value="" autofocus autocomplete="off" />
                <span class="error" id="password_error"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '' ?>" />
                    <span class="error" id="email_error"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="rpassword">Retype Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="rpassword" name="rpassword" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['rpassword']) ? $_POST['rpassword'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="fname">Full Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="contact">Contact Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contact']) ? $_POST['contact'] : '' ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="dob">Date of Birth</label></td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="dd" name="dd" style="width:24px;" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['dd']) ? $_POST['dd'] : '' ?>" placeholder="dd" />&nbsp;/
            <input type="text" id="mm" name="mm" style="width:24px;" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['mm']) ? $_POST['mm'] : '' ?>" placeholder="mm" />&nbsp;/
            <input type="text" id="yy" name="yy" style="width:40px;" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['yy']) ? $_POST['yy'] : '' ?>" placeholder="yyyy" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="r"><label for="capcha"></label></td>
            <td>
            <div style="padding-bottom:3px;">
            <img id="captcha" src="inc/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='inc/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false" class="capcha">Refresh</a>
            </div>
            <div><input type="text" name="ct_captcha" size="12" maxlength="8" id="capcha" style="width:100px;" /></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn" id="btn_register">Proceed</a>&nbsp;<span id="wait"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The main changes in this form is that I have made is that I have added `<span class="error" id="password_error"></span>` and `<span class="error" id="email_error"></span>` to hold the error content if error occurs on submit for password and email.

When you click on proceed the error messages are emptied and call is sent to the server. The server responds with success or error message which is in json format. In the response we will check whether the server responded with success message or error message. That is done using  `response.success == 'success'` . If the response is success then the form has been successfully submitted.

If the response is not success then we will check what type of error is sent by the server, whether it is for email or for password. We will check for the type of error response using 
`response.error.email != ''` and `response.error.password != ''`. These will check for email and password errors. If the error is found then the error message response is inserted in to the corresponding error message tag using the id we already added.

I have done for email and password. Similarly you can do for all the fields. You need to just add the error message holder to the html at the correct place.

**Request.php**

```
<?php

include('connectdb.php');
include('functions.php');

$email      = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($_POST['email'])));
$password   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

$message = array();

if(!check_email_address($email)){
    $message['error']['email']  = "Invalid Email Address";
}
if(empty($password) || strlen($password) < 0){
    $message['error']['password'] = "Invalid Password";
}

// if there are no errors return success callback
if(!isset($message['error'])){
    $message['success'] = "success";
}


echo json_encode($message);

?>
```

In request.php what I have changed is removed the `$error` variable and created a new array `$message` and added the error message in a multidimensional array containing error as primary key and the field name as the secondary key of the array.

The advantage of doing this is that we can easily parse error message with field name in the ajax callback.

If no error message is found then we will add the success message to the `$message` array with key success.

Hope you are clear . Let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: its work awesome, thank you so much, the only drawback is the invalid message is still appear when the field is in valid input, how can I hide the message when the user is correct the valid input again?

Comment: @conmen when you submit the form again the error messages will go. Are you thinking of removing the error message when the user types valid input without submittin ??

Answer (score 0):

You should also provide error callback. It may possible that server is throwing error

```
$('#btn_register').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#reg_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "error"){
                alert('Error: '+ output_str);
                //$('#msg').html(output_str);
            }else{
                alert(output_str);

            }
        },
        error:function(){
             console.log(arguments);
        }
    });

});
```